# What is the product: Ethyne + (conc)KMnO4?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

In cold and alkaline medium it gives ethane-1,2-dial. But what happens in conc KMnO4? Does it give CO2? Also, what will happen to other triple bond containing hydrocarbons?

Comment: Further oxidation of oxalic acid will give 2 x CO2. Other hydrocarbon alkynes will give the pair of carboxylic acids corresponding to cleavage across the triple bond